# how to synchronize with changes from repository in subversive?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

there is update and update to revision

what is the difference ? It appears that "update" should be the same as "update to revision" head revision. I am very confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. `svn update` is the same as updating to the HEAD revision.

Comment: I see that Update corresponds to svn update "c:\proj1" -r HEAD --depth infinity and 
Update to revision head correspinds to svn update "c:\proj1" -r HEAD
 So I am not sure what the difference in commands are doing

Comment: The additional option `--depth infinity` causes SVN to update the target folder, its file and directory children, its children's children, and so on to full recursion. If this option is omitted, then the update depth will be taken from the so-called *ambient depth*, which is the depth that was recorded when the repository was checked out in the first place. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html. So in short, *Update* will also check out the HEAD revision of any nested items if they haven't been checked out so far.

Comment: so better to use update for regular use ? if all I have to do is synch with changes made to repository and I am not using not caring about depth of the project. I just need all of it

Comment: If you don't care about depth, then your ambient depth is very likely to be infinity anyway. In which case there isn't a difference between the two methods.